# Wordpress Pagination not working, it would not move to the next page

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

Currently, I'm using wp_query to display my articles on the blog page, however. I got into a problem with paginations. after implementing the pagination code into my wp_query (Please see code below), the pagination would not work, everytime I press page 2 or next page it still show's the first page. Also, when I hover the pagination numbers and next button it shows the links are all the same.

Here's my php code.

```
<?php 

$args = array('post_status' => 'publish');
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
$big = 99999999999999;
if($wp_query->have_posts()) :
 while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();?>
    <a href="<?php echo the_permalink() ?>"><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
    <p><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'large', array( 'class' => 'img-responsive' )); ?></p>         
    <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
) );
?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Hopefully, you can enlighten me about my problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: first please change your variable `$wp_query` as its default wordpress variable may be this variable causing issue

Comment: no luck. I changed all my $wp_query variables and still don't work. It still shows the first page articles after I clicked the page 2

Comment: please add `'paged' => $paged` in this `$args = array('post_status' => 'publish');` like `$args = array('post_status' => 'publish','paged' => $paged);`

Comment: I just added 'paged' => $paged under $args array. But there is a problem after I clicked the page 2 all the articles/contents in the page were gone

Comment: please add `$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;` above your `$args` array

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me. Try this:

```
<?php 
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array('post_status' => 'publish','paged' => $paged);
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
$big = 99999999999999;
if($wp_query->have_posts()) :
 while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();?>
    <a href="<?php echo the_permalink() ?>"><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
    <p><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'large', array( 'class' => 'img-responsive' )); ?></p>         
    <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
) );
?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: No luck too. I implemented your code on my custom page but after I clicked the page 2 all the articles/contents were gone :( I'm using Wordpress default post on my articles and I used WP_Query to display the post in my custom blog page.

Comment: Your site is on local or on sever ?? can you send a site link?  then i`ll check max pages.

Comment: Sorry I cannot send you a link as of this time because I'm developing it on my local server